# Why does var infer type object and not XmlNode in XmlNodeList loop?

Tags: c#, xml, type-inference

If one loops through an XmlNodeList like this

```
foreach (XmlNode foo in xmlNodeList) {string baa = foo.Attributes["baa"].Value;}
```

everything works as expected - foo is clearly of type *XmlNode* and the VS.NET IDE shows methods and fields.

On the other hand

```
foreach (var foo in xmlNodeList) { string baa = foo.Attributes["baa"].Value; }
```

is not compiling because here foo is of type *object*. Type inference sort of works but infers *object*.

Apparently, the elements of XmlNodeList are not of *one* defined type, but assigning them to XmlNode instead of var does something implicitly (casting or unboxing).

First question: what's the mechanism behind that?

Second (related) question: how to find the types one can use in this kind of loop? Does the VS.NET IDE help?

Comment: You may wish to use the classes in the system.xml.linq namespace as they do implement the generic versions IEnumerable among others.  The var should be inferred correctly when using these classes. YMMV

Comment: @Chris: Thanks for the hint - I'll check.

Comment: +1, I was just going to ask the same question :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`XmlNodeList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnodelist.aspx) implements only the non-generic `IEnumerable` interface, and not something like `IEnumerable<XmlNode>` with generics. This prevents strong typing of its elements until you cast appropriately, so the compiler has no choice but to map the implicit type declaration to `object` in your foreach.

If you insist on using the `var` keyword, you can cast the elements of `xmlNodeList` like so:

```
foreach (var foo in xmlNodeList.Cast<XmlNode>())
{
    string baa = foo.Attributes["baa"].Value;
}
```

But that's ugly, and requires more keystrokes anyway. You may as well just explicitly declare `XmlNode foo`, and let the foreach cast it for you on the fly.

Comment: Thanks very  much, understood! I don't want ugly, but as I wrote in my comment to Jon the  question had partly a practical part: if Resharper gives me 'var', what's the fastest way to find the real type?

Comment: As Daniel Hilgarth points out, the easiest way to do it is by looking at the documentation.

Answer (score 4):

As BoltClock notes, `XmlNodeList` only implements `IEnumerable`.

The `foreach` loop automatically does casting for you behind the scenes, so this:

```
List<object> values = new List<object> { "x", "y", "z" };
foreach (string x in values)
{
    ...
}
```

is entirely legal, and performs a cast (which can throw an exception, of course) on each value.

It's not really clear to me what you mean by your second question - but I'd just recommend that you explicitly use `XmlNode` in your loop. If you *really* want to use `var`, you could write:

```
foreach (var foo in xmlNodeList.Cast<XmlNode>())
```

but that feels like overkill to me...

Comment: Thanks, IEnumerable vs. IEnumerable<T> explains it! With my second question I meant: in a case like this, what's the fastest way to find the item type I need, in this case 'XmlNode'? Resharper gives me 'var', so I was wondering if the VS.NET has it somewhere hidden in its intellisense.

Comment: @Olaf: No, there can't be any Intellisense on this, because the information simply isn't there. You need to know what you're doing - which you should anyway, of course :)

Comment: That's what I wanted to know (the information simply not being there). Thanks for helping me know what I'm doing!

Answer (score 4):

[XmlNodeList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnodelist.aspx) has been in the .NET Framework before it supported generics. Because of that, it implements only the non-generic interface `IEnumerable` and not the generic `IEnumerable<T>`.
To know which types can be in this list you need to read the documentation. The best way is the [indexer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnodelist.item.aspx).

BTW: The IDE hasn't been called VS.NET since Visual Studio 2005 was released :-) It is called VS only since then.

Comment: Thanks, also for the VS.NET hint (we are still using it internally)!