# Why does var infer type X509Certificate2 and not object in X509Certificate2Collection loop?

Tags: c#, generics

There are many questions ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9127142/why-does-var-infer-type-object-and-not-xmlnode-in-xmlnodelist-loop) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4933711/var-type-inference-in-c-sharp) [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2786727/why-does-var-evaluate-to-system-object-in-foreach-var-row-in-table-rows)) about why `var` picks up the `object` type in a `foreach` loop, but this time it's different. When I use this code snippet to loop through a `X509Certificate2Collection`, it surprised me that `var` actually picked up the `X509Certificate2` type, instead of `object`, although `X509Certificate2Collection` only implements the non-generic `IEnumerable` and not `IEnumerable<T>`!

```
X509Certificate2Collection collection = new X509Certificate2Collection();
foreach (var cert in collection)
{
    Console.WriteLine(cert.Subject);
}
```

You can see the inheritance hierarchy in the [msdn article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2collection.aspx), but it doesn't seem to be implementing `IEnumerable<X509Certificate2>`. If I use LINQ on the collection, I do not get the `X509Certificate2` type:

```
collection.Select(cert => cert.Subject); // Won't compile
```

So how does the compiler know the actual type in the `var` case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`X509Certificate2Collection.getEnumerator()` returns an `X509Certificate2Enumerator`, which has a `Current` property of type `X509Certificate2`.

In other words, c# is not relying solely on IEnumerable or IEnumerable<T>.  It's looking at that `Current` property directly.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288257%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Comment: amended with link to the documentation